# Is there an API for iPhone development to disable mail/sms?

Tags: ios, email, sms

Is there an API for iPhone development to disable mail/SMS? I could not find one.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. You want to do what? What do you mean by "disable mail/sms"?

Comment: Why would you want to disable two key functions of the iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

no. There isn't.

I can't think of a reason why a user would want an app to be able to do that!

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is not a way for an iPhone app to prevent the operation of other applications, including built-in ones like mail.

The closest thing to this kind of capability is if you are configuring iOS devices in an Enterprise environment, you have the ability to add certain restrictions (disable camera, prevent installing apps,...) as part of the [configuration profile](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf) you install on the device. (Although even in that case, "disable mail" and "disable SMS" don't seem to be options
Apple provides).

Comment: Thanks :( Trsut me there is a reason, to do it...Will look for some other way.

Comment: There isn't any other way unless you jailbreak and delete those apps.